# Changing the order of integration for $\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2z}\int_{y}^{2y}f(x,y,z)dxdydz$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

I need to change the order of integration (without drawing the field) for:

$\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{2z}\int_{y}^{2y}f(x,y,z)dxdydz$

to $\int\int\int f(x,y,z)dzdxdy$ and $\int\int\int f(x,y,z)dxdzdy$

I got to

$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{y}^{2y}\int_{\frac{x}{4}}^{2}f(x,y,z)dzdxdy$

and

$\int_{0}^{4}\int_{\frac{y}{2}}^{2}\int_{0}^{4z}f(x,y,z)dxdzdy$

which are incorrect apparently. What am I doing wrong? When it comes to the intervals, this is how I got to them:

$0 \leq z \leq 2$, $0 \leq y \leq 2z$, $y \leq x \leq 2y$, and so for the first integral:

$\frac{y}{4} \leq \frac{x}{4} \leq \frac{y}{2} \leq z \leq 2$, so $\frac{x}{4} \leq z \leq 2$

and for the second integral:
$\frac{y}{2} \leq z \leq 2$, and $0 \leq y\leq x \leq 2y \leq 4z$ so $0 \leq x \leq 4z$

Comment: For the second integral, you're only swapping $y,z$ (the two outer variables). So the inner $x$ integral shouldn't change. The two outer parts are correct.

Comment: So I don't need to change the inner integral at all in this case?

Comment: Correct. If it makes it easier to think about, the inner integral (after integrating out $x$) is just some function of $y,z$. You wouldn't normally change the integrand when swapping the order of integration.